# Git confusion - getting git repo on server after switch from svn

Tags: git, git-svn

I have a 3 year old svn repo I just converted to git using git-svn.  Then I cloned the new repo and want to copy it to a our main server (running ssh).

The git project is organized like this:

```
~/server.com/
~/server.com/.git
~/server.com/htdocs
~/server.com/includes
etc.
```

Following the instructions in the gitpro book, it says to use scp -r to copy it to the server, but I'm ending up copying the checked-out/cloned files, not just the git stuff, which I don't want (according to the book it should be "bare").  Do I just do "> scp -r ~/server.com/.git user@other.server:/path/to/git-files"? And then clone via "> git clone user@other.server:/path/to/git-files/server.com/.git"?

Also, the repo's they toss around in the gitpro book are like "server.git"; is that just a naming convention?

Links:

http://www.jonmaddox.com/2008/03/05/cleanly-migrate-your-subversion-repository-to-a-git-repository/
http://progit.org/book/ch4-2.html

TIA,
Hans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, confusion cleared up, I needed to do this, which didn't resonate with me at first:

git clone --bare server.com-git-svn server.git

Then scp.  FYI for future searchers...